# Java - date, format, time zones and Spring Boot defaults

Tags: java, date, spring-boot, timezone

I have simple Java object with a date field:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private Date date;
```

When I investigate the date with debugger I see:

```
Wed Jun 14 00:00:00 BST 2017
```

But once I return it with `Spring boot` `controller` I get:

```
"date": "2017-06-13 23:00:00"
```

1. What's causing the difference?
2. Why Java treats the date as `BST`?
3. Does Java `Date` class contain time-zone information or just plain timestamp in long format?
4. Is `Spring boot` using `UTC` format by default while serialising DTOs to JSON?

Comment: in debugger you see the default Date.toString output, read more at https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: Date class does not support time zones, and it is always effectively in UTC. Occasionally, UTC might be displayed as BST, which is "British Standard Time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.Date` has no timezone information (only the `long` timestamp), but it uses the system's default timezone in the `toString()` method - you can find more info about this [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date) (as already suggested in the comments).

Just check the value of `TimeZone.getDefault()`. It'll probably be `Europe/London` - as London in now in summer time, the short name (used by `Date.toString()`) of this timezone is `BST`.

As your output suggests, Spring is probably using `UTC` (as `2017-06-13 23:00:00` in `UTC` is `2017-06-14 00:00:00` in `BST`).